# How to prove by induction that binary search tree is of AVL type?

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree, induction, proof-of-correctness

Could you please help how to prove by induction that current algorithm which tests if the binary search tree is of AVL type is correct?

```
int checkHeight(TreeNode root){
 if(root == null)       
    return 0;

 int leftHeight := checkHeight(root.left); 
 if(leftHeight == -1)   
    return -1;  

 int rightHeight := checkHeight(root.right); 
 if(rightHeight == -1)  
    return -1;

 int heightDiff := Math.abs(leftHeight - rightHeight);
 if(heightDiff > 1)         
    return -1;
 else
    return max(leftHeight, rightHeight) + 1;
}
```

I tried such proof.

**Basis:** root is null - return 0.

**Induction step:** if we have a tree, where B is a root then in the leaf levels the height is 0, moving to the top we take max(0, 0) = 0 and add 1. The height is correct. Calculating the difference between the height of left node and the height of the right one 0-0 = 0 we obtain that it is not bigger than 1. The result is 0+1 =1 - the correct height. For all binary search trees, such algorithm is correct.